# Firebase data structure for iOS app with profiles and basic gamification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am currently building out my iOS 10 app with user profiles, which should hold certain achievements and experience points (similar system to StackOverflow). I have already built my Facebook Login, FIRAuth etc. At the moment I am thinking about the data structure of Firebase's DB. I have read through the [Firebase Guide for flat data structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data) and some general Firebase data guides like the one from [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/109706/firebase-tutorial-getting-started).

This is what users can **already** do:

- login with Facebook (...) and get picture, name etc. (already handled via FIRAuth)
- visit a profile page, which shows their name and profile picture (already handled in a ProfileViewController)

This is my **to-do** list:

- basic achievements via badges/titles similarly to StackExchange/StackOverflow e.g. user has done action XY 20 times => badge for 20 times for action XY; I was thinking of either:

  a) having an array/list in each of the users' profile, which holds all of the gathered badges (as strings) OR

  b) having a single boolean var for each achievement within the user profiles
- a second achievements tracker, which tracks the general usage of the app -  something like a levelling system in RPG games with experience points so just an Int value for every profile in terms of the DB

**My question:**

How would you combine the FIRAuth profiles with the database to hold the aforementioned badges (could be up-to 50-60 achievements) and the separate levels/xp points of the users?

Keep in mind that I am new to the modelling of JSON DBs. I *don't* want a solution in terms of code etc. for the functions in question - just a helping hand for the data structure of the user profiles.

I would also be looking into the extension of the user profiles in the future (messaging etc.) and I should be able to send notifications to all users who have certain levels/achievements in the future (and this makes me lean towards b)) - so too much nesting is out of the question already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the structure below, you can retrieve a particular user's achievements by observing the children of the user's achievements path. However this only get's you the keys of the achievements.

Given you have a user with the uid `1j6Ft1BT30TFG403obvGfjOHE4th`, for each child in `user-achievements/1j6Ft1BT30TFG403obvGfjOHE4th`, you can use the child keys to observe the value of each achievement at `achievements/-KQpsPExLsKdnVHMliiP`.

```
{
    "users": {
        "1j6Ft1BT30TFG403obvGfjOHE4th": {
            "username": "john"
        }
    },
    "user-achievements": {
        "1j6Ft1BT30TFG403obvGfjOHE4th": {
            "-KQpsPExLsKdnVHMliiP": true
        }
    },
    "achievements": {
        "-KQpsPExLsKdnVHMliiP": {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am guessing it's doable, I'd add the xp thing to "users"? If I was to send a notification to all users with a certain achievement, I'd have to parse "user-achievements" -> then for each uid the child with the achievement (and if I don't know the index I'd have to parse all for the proper key). Is there a way to flatten this or is this not considered expensive in terms of bandwidth? I am talking lots of users with the mentioned 50 vars for the achievements each. But if I do know the index of the right achievement, it would be pretty easy I guess

Comment: @tech4242 you can add XP to users indeed. Sorting users by XP for example would require you to order the `/users` path by the child key `XP`. In terms of sending a notification to the users that have a particular achievement, you can use FCM Topics. When a user receives an achievement, you can subscribe this user to `/topics/achievements_-KQpsPExLsKdnVHMliiP`. In your console, you will be able to send notifications to this topic or by using FCM [link](http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) for something a little more automated.